# Insufficient padding on one-line markdown pre tag

Tags: bug, design, markdown, code-block

When scrolling through a code-block that is one line high on OSX the scroll bars appear when you hover over to scroll and obscure over half of the text.

Chrome:
[image: obscured text Chrome]
Firefox:
[image: obscured text Firefox]

It's very distracting. It seems like the addition of some padding to the container `<pre>` tag makes this disappearing/reappearing scrollbar effect much less obtrusive.

[image: increased padding]
That's probably a bit much I've added in the screenshot, but I just quickly did it and took the capture. Even if it is just on Mac, it's pretty annoying.

#### Live example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

#### Screenshots' source SO post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34131942/1252748

#### Browser versions:

- Google Chrome, Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit)
- Mozilla FireFox 43.0.2

Comment: What browser? It might be one that is not supported.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Google Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit).

Comment: Cheers, so this should be fixed. Please add it to the question as well

Comment: The post where you saw this?

Comment: @ShadowWizard. Added.

Comment: Padding looks ok from Firefox.

Comment: @Braiam I've Added that now.

Comment: @Braiam Looks the same for me if Firefox. I added a screenshot.

Comment: Might have to do with themes?

Comment: Eh, seems like disabling overlay scrollbars (System Preferences -> Show scrollbars -> Always) would be the preferred solution if you don't like this behaviour of your OS

Comment: @TimStone Yes, that's fixed it for me. Thanks!